# Does spring-data-elasticsearch support search_after?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using spring-data-elasticsearch version 4.1.3 currently. We need to use ES deep paging and it's `search_after` feature.  Looking at the spring-data-elasticsearch `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/NativeSearchQueryBuilder.html), it does not look like ES `search_after` is supported.  I might not look at the right place or there is a way to incorporate `search_after` into the query builder that I don't know.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The link doesn't work now

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported, there is [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1684) to have this implemented.

**Edit 25.09.2022:**

Support for the Point In Time API is contained since version 5.0M6 and is either available now from the milestone releases or with the release of version 5 in November 2022.

Comment: Thanks! Will be looking out for the new release.